# Opacity fade determined by values pulled from a form.

Tags: javascript

I have the opacity of 10 boxes being triggered on submit and the values of the opacities being determined by the values pulled from the form. What I need to do now is have it running through a loop rather than just assigning variables to each box separately. This is the code I have.

```
var color;
var count = 0;
var colorOpac = [];

function init() {

    var val1 = document.querySelector('#question1').value; 
    var opacity1 = val1 * 0.1;
    colorOpac.push(opacity1);

    var val2 = document.querySelector('#question2').value;
    var opacity2 = val2 * 0.1;
    colorOpac.push(opacity2);

    var val3 = document.querySelector('#question3').value;
    var opacity3 = val3 * 0.1;
    colorOpac.push(opacity3);

    var val4 = document.querySelector('#question4').value;
    var opacity4 = val4 * 0.1;
    colorOpac.push(opacity4);

    var val5 = document.querySelector('#question5').value;
    var opacity5 = val5 * 0.1;
    colorOpac.push(opacity5);

    var val6 = document.querySelector('#question6').value;
    var opacity6 = val6 * 0.1;
    colorOpac.push(opacity6);

    var val7 = document.querySelector('#question7').value;
    var opacity7 = val7 * 0.1;
    colorOpac.push(opacity7);

    var val8 = document.querySelector('#question8').value;
    var opacity8 = val8 * 0.1;
    colorOpac.push(opacity8);

    var val9 = document.querySelector('#question9').value;
    var opacity9 = val9 * 0.1;
    colorOpac.push(opacity9);

    var val10 = document.querySelector('#question10').value;
    var opacity10 = val10 * 0.1;
    colorOpac.push(opacity10);

    color = document.querySelectorAll(".box"); 
    setInterval(fade, 50);
}

function fade() {
    for(i=0; i <color.length;i++){
    if(count < colorOpac[i]){
        color[i].style.opacity = count;
    }
}
    count = count + 0.01;
}
```

I found an example I think might work, but all it does is pull the value and loop through, where I need to integrate this line var opacity1 = val1 * 0.1;. This is the example I found.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    values.push(elems[i].value);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried manipulating the example above to work with mine with no success. Thanks :)

Comment: please set up a http://jsfiddle.net example with your attempt so far

Comment: Sorry! I'm pretty new to using resources like stackoverflow and jsfiddle. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/QS2g5/7/. The way my JS is set up the opacity animation only happens on submit, not sure how to achieve that on jsfiddle as I only saw that onLoad and onDomready were options. So right now that animation is not happening. What it should be doing is once numbers are input into each field (1-10) the opacity will fade in onsubmit for each box.

Comment: so basically, you want the opacity to fade only when all boxes are full? or for each one as soon as a number is inserted? also, would you be willing to try a jQuery solution which will be simpler or you prefer to keep it in pure javascript?

Comment: What I have happening now is that after I put the values into the form and hit submit, all of the boxes fade in at the same time to the corresponding opacity. What I'm looking to do now, is rather than have that huge chunk of code targeting input id individually, I was hoping to target the input element and cycle through them with a loop if possible? I just want to condense the code I have now. And it has to be pure Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

well i couldnt get your fiddle to work, but:

you could set a class to each of your inputs "AnswerInput" , get all of them and cycle through them as follows:

```
var answerInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("AnswerInput");

for(i = 0; i< answerInputs.length; i ++)
{
   answerInputs[i] ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question again. Got rid of all of the code that looks like this:

```
var val1 = document.querySelector('#question1').value; 
var opacity1 = val1 * 0.1;
colorOpac.push(opacity1);
```

and condensed it down to this:

```
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    colorOpac.push(inputs[i].value * 0.1);
}
```